# How to compare two instances of an object Python?

Tags: python, equality

Attempting to compare two objects' data members; however, the error message has no specific details, which leaves me with little information on how to go about correcting it

```
class Person: 
  def __init__(self, name, age, id):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    self.id = id

  def same_person(Person lhs, Person rhs):
    return lhs.id == rhs.id

person1 = Person("David Joyner", 30, 901234567)
person2 = Person("D. Joyner", 29, 901234567)
person3 = Person("David Joyner", 30, 903987654)
# print calls provided as part of an exercise: not my implementation
print(same_person(person1, person2))
print(same_person(person1, person3))
```

- Python 3.6.5
- Command: python person.py
- Error message
- [image: SyntaxError]
- If it were an indentation level the following error is displayed
- [image: IndentationError]

Comment: Among other things, you are probably mixing tabs and spaces in your indentation somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers are correct and provide the best way to do it, but I realized that you wrote:

> print calls provided as part of an exercise: not my implementation

```
print(same_person(person1, person2))
print(same_person(person1, person3))
```

The exercise probably wants you to define a function outside the class. You can do that by removing that function from the class and writing it un-indented outside the class (without providing class type too). For example:

```
class Person: 
    def __init__(self, name, age, id):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.id = id

def same_person(lhs, rhs):
    return lhs.id == rhs.id

person1 = Person("David Joyner", 30, 901234567)
person2 = Person("D. Joyner", 29, 901234567)
person3 = Person("David Joyner", 30, 903987654)

print(same_person(person1, person2))
print(same_person(person1, person3))
```

Comment: Much appreciated

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Comment: @aguilar keep in mind that the best way to compare two objects would be overriding `__eq__()` method of the class, have a look at [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__)

Answer (score 3):

same_person is a method of the class `Person` and should take just an argument as input. It should be defined as:

```
def same_person(self, other):
    return self.id == other.id
```

and called as

```
person1.same_person(person2)
```

or you could override the `__eq__` method (i.e., `==`).

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.id == other.id
```

in order to be able to do it as `person1 == person2`

Comment: `return self is other` is a bit more elegant.

Comment: @DYZ: but then `Person(1, 2, 3) != Person(1, 2, 3)`, since they're not the same object.

Comment: If you suggest to add  `self.id is other.id` I don't really understand why, we are checking equality not object identity.

Comment: I suggest to replace `self.id == other.id` with `self is other` (both expressions are fully equivalent).

Answer (score 1):

```
class Person: 
   def __init__(self, name, age, id):
      self.name = name
      self.age = age
      self.id = id

   def same_person(self, lhs, rhs):
      return lhs.id == rhs.id
```

you dont have to define lhs and rhs type in python unless you are using typings.

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few mistakes:

1. The arguments in the method cannot be preceded by the `Person` classname
2. You have not defined instances `person1`, `person2` and `person3`
3. If you define an instance method (`same_person`), it should be used ON an instance.

This is what I would do:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age, id):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.id = id

    def same_person(self, other):
        return self.id == other.id

person1 = Person("Bob", 25, 1)
person2 = Person("Mike", 33, 1)
person3 = Person("Maria", 28, 2)

print(person1.same_person(person2))
print(person1.same_person(person3))
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better rewrite **eq**  to compare objects:

```
class Person: 
    def __init__(self, name, age, id):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.id = id
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.id == other.id
```

```
person1 = Person("Bob", 25, 1)
person2 = Person("Mike", 33, 1)
person3 = Person("Maria", 28, 2)

print(person1 == person2)
print(person1 == person3)
```

```
>>> True
>>> False
```

https://devinpractice.com/2016/11/29/python-objects-comparison/